# is there a compatibility checker at XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Can XCode check for the code compatibility against a specific OS X version? or an external tool?

I have a project that's using a function exists at 10.9 and newer, though I set xcode deployment target to 10.7, it builds without errors but when trying to run the application on 10.8, it doesn't work!!

how can I get functions minimum OS version required?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not provide a tool to check whether a method is available for the deployment target. But if you know that some method is only available from a specific version you can check whether the method is available:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(newMethodNotAlwaysAvailable:withParameters:)]) {
    [self newMethodNotAlwaysAvailable:@"1" withParameters:YES];
}
else {
    // Call some other method to just don't do anything.
}
```

You can also do ut for classes:

```
if ([SomeNewClass Class] ) {
    // Class is available and you can use it
}
```

Comment: yes, it's a good way to check at runtime, but I want to check at build time. why xcode build a code that can't run on 10.7 though the build target is 10.7? I need something like a tool that will iterate over all the project's functions and tell me that the minimum required version is X

Comment: Request for tool, libraries are offtopic for Stackoverflow, but there is such a tool: [Deploymate for Xcode](http://www.deploymateapp.com)

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, and sorry for the offtopic post, I didn't know about it